# Trying to print all prime numbers below two million

Tags: python, math

I was trying to print the sum of every prime number below two million, it should print 142913828922 but it´s printing 142913827513.
How can I get the right number?

*This is my code:*

```
def SumOfPrimesBelow(num):
    contador = 0
    primos = []
    for c in range(1, int(math.sqrt(num))):
        for c2 in range(1, c):
            if c % c2 == 0:
                contador += 1
        if contador == 1:
            primos.append(c)
        contador = 0
    primos2 = []
    for c in range(1, num):
        for num5 in primos:
            if c != num5:
                if c % num5 == 0:
                    break
        if c % num5 == 0:
                continue
        if c != 1:
            primos2.append(c)
    cont = 0
    for num in primos2:
        cont += num
    return cont


print(SumOfPrimesBelow(2000000))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is off by 1409, the prime number that you code failed to capture in `primos2` due to the following reason:

After this loop

```py
for num5 in primos:
    if c != num5:
        if c % num5 == 0:
            break
```

`num5` has a value of 1409 (the last element of `primos`). Therefore, for loop `c = 1409`, the `continue` line will be executed and 1409 will not be appended to `primos2`.

This can be resolved by changing the line `if c % num5 == 0:` to `if c % num5 == 0 and c != num5:`

Answer (score 0):

When you write the two lines of code:

```py
if c % num5 == 0:
    continue
```

You're actually outside of the `for num5 in primos:` loop.

So what do you expect the value of `num5` to be in that case, and what is the logic of these two lines?

If you simply remove these two lines, your code should work as expected.

But actually, you can make your code even simpler and more efficient by starting the big loop at `int(math.sqrt(num))` instead of at 1. Indeed, you've already computed the prime numbers below this threshold, so there is no need to compute them again.

Also, since you're only interested in the sum, you don't need to store the whole list `primos2`. You can add the prime numbers to `cont` directly.

I've also slightly modified your code to use `math.isqrt` instead of `int(math.sqrt(...))`; and to use `all(...)` and `any(...)` which increases readability and avoids `break` and `continue`. In general I very strongly discourage the use of `break` and `continue`. For-loops are easy to read because they have a straightforward logic. Breaking that logic with `break` is deceptive for people who read your code.

Finally:

```py
from math import isqrt

def SumOfPrimesBelow(num):
    primos = []
    threshold = isqrt(num)
    for c in range(2, threshold):
        if not any(c % c2 == 0 for c2 in range(2, c)):
            primos.append(c)
    cont = sum(primos)
    for c in range(threshold, num):
        if all(c % prime != 0 for prime in primos):
            cont += c
    return cont

print(SumOfPrimesBelow(2000000))
```

Output:

```
142913828922
```